# How to keep the data from the store?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My application has an ad section in which by clicking on the button see more you access the detail of that ad, the detail is managed by redux, it works well, the only drawback is that when reloading the page the data that I bring from the store appears. How can I do so that these data remain when refreshing the page?

```
///detail
export const AdvertismentsDetail = () => {

    const currentAdvertisment = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.selectedAdvertisments);
    const session = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.session);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState (false);
  return (
        <>
            <div className="fixNotchMarginTop bg-teal-600 fixed block md:hidden w-full z-20 left-0 top-0 pt-2 pb-2 flex items-center justify-start header-top">
                <Link className="w-full pb-3 font-medium text-lg text-white hover:text-white flex items-center" to="/college/advertismentslist">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-arrow-left stroke-white hover:stroke-white h-6" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                        <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                        <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12" />
                        <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="11" y2="18" />
                        <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="11" y2="6" />
                    </svg>
                    <span className="news-detail-title ml-2">{currentAdvertisment?.title}</span>
                </Link>
            </div>
            <div key={currentAdvertisment?.id} className="columns-1 mx-auto px-2 main-container pb-12">
                <div className="card bg-white px-2 py-3 md:p-6 my-3">
                    <Link className="w-full hidden md:flex pb-3 font-medium text-neutral-800 hover:text-teal-600 flex items-center" to="/college/advertismentslist">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-arrow-left stroke-neutral-800 hover:stroke-teal-600" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" fill="none" strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round">
                            <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />
                            <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12" />
                            <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="11" y2="18" />
                            <line x1="5" y1="12" x2="11" y2="6" />
                        </svg>
                        <h1 className="font-medium text-neutral-800 text-xl text-center ml-2 news-detail-title">{currentAdvertisment?.title}</h1>
                    </Link>
                    <div className="card-body px-2">
                        <div className="" >
                            <div className="mb-2">
                                <span className="text-neutral-800 text-sm font-medium">Fecha de creación:</span>
                                {/* <span className="text-teal-600 text-sm mb-4 mx-2">{format ( new Date (currentAdvertisment?.publishStartDate), 'EEE dd/MM/Y ', { locale: es }).toUpperCase()}</span> */}
                            </div>

                            <div className="mb-2">
                                <span className="text-neutral-800 text-sm font-medium">Título:</span>
                                <span className="text-sm text-neutral-600 font-normal mx-2">{currentAdvertisment?.title}</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-2">
                                <span className="text-neutral-800 text-sm font-medium">Descripción:</span>
                                <div className="text-neutral-600 font-sans news-text-description" ><p className="parrafo">{currentAdvertisment?.description}</p></div>
                            </div>
                            {currentAdvertisment?.imagePath ?
                            <div className="mb-2">
                                <span className="text-neutral-800 text-sm font-medium">Imagen:</span>
                                <img className="rounded-lg my-2 w-1/2 md:w-1/3 h-32 md:h-96 object-cover object-center" src={contentUtils.getLargeImageUrlAdvertisments(currentAdvertisment?.imagePath)} alt="Sin imagen" />
                            
                            </div>
                            :<div></div>
                            }
                            <div className="mb-2">
                                <span className="text-neutral-800 text-sm font-medium">Categoría:</span>
                                {currentAdvertisment?.categoryId === 0 ?
                                <div className="text-neutral-600 font-normal text-sm news-text-description">Alquiler</div>
                                :null
                                }
                                {currentAdvertisment?.categoryId === 1 ?
                                <div className="text-neutral-600 font-normal text-sm news-text-description">Compra</div>
                                :null}
                                {currentAdvertisment?.categoryId === 2 ?
                                <div className="text-neutral-600 font-normal text-sm news-text-description">Traspaso</div>
                                :null
                                }
                                {currentAdvertisment?.categoryId === 3 ?
                                <div className="text-neutral-600 font-normal text-sm news-text-description">Venta</div>
                                :null
                                }
                            </div>
                            <div className="mb-2">
                                <span className="text-neutral-800 text-sm font-medium">Provincia:</span>
                                {currentAdvertisment?.province === "V" ? 
                                        <p className="text-neutral-600 text-xs font-normal creator-text px-2">Provincia: Valencia</p>
                                        :null}
                                        {currentAdvertisment?.province === "A" ? 
                                        <p className="text-neutral-600 text-xs font-normal creator-text px-2">Provincia: Alicante</p>
                                        :null}
                                        {currentAdvertisment?.province === "C" ? 
                                        <p className="text-neutral-600 text-xs font-normal creator-text px-2">Provincia: Castellón</p>
                                        :null}
                            </div>
                            <h2 className="text-neutral-800 font-medium my-3  border-neutral-300">Datos de contacto</h2>
                            <div className="text-neutral-600 font-normal text-sm news-text-description">Nombre: {currentAdvertisment?.contactFirstname}</div>
                            <div className="text-neutral-600 font-normal text-sm news-text-description">Apellido: {currentAdvertisment?.contactLastname}</div>
                            <div className="text-neutral-600 font-normal text-sm news-text-description">Telefono: {currentAdvertisment?.contactPhone}</div>
                            <div className="text-neutral-600 font-normal text-sm news-text-description">Email: <a>{currentAdvertisment?.contactEmail} </a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
)}

///advertisments lis
export const AdvertismentsList = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const store = useStore();
    const navigate = useNavigate();

 function handleAddToDetail(advertisment) {
        setIsLoading(true);
        getAdvertismentById(advertisment.id)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            dispatch(selectAdvertisments(response));
            navigate('advertismentsdetail/'+advertisment.id);
            setIsLoading(false);
        }).catch((error) => {
            setIsLoading(false);
            console.error(error);
            throw error;
        });
    }

 <div className="icofcv-ad-list-container">
            {advertismentsList.map((advertisment) => (
                <>
                <div id="myTabContent">
               
                {showTabRent === true && advertisment.categoryId === 0 && advertisment.publishEndDate && advertisment.publishEndDate >  new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -8) && advertisment.status.toString() == "2" && advertisment.publishStartDate &&  advertisment.publishStartDate <  new Date().toISOString().slice(0, -8) ?
                    <div className="p-0" id="rent" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="rent-tab">
                        <div className="bg-white px-0 pt-3 border-b rounded-0 block">
                            <button type="button" className="text-left mb-2" onClick={() => handleAddToDetail(advertisment)}>
                                <div className="flex items-top flex-col md:flex-row md:items-center">
                                    <div className="md:w-100 h-auto pb-2">
                                        <small   className="text-teal-600 mb-2 px-2">Fecha publicación: {format ( new Date (advertisment.creationDate), 'EEE dd/MM/Y ', { locale: es }).toUpperCase()}</small>
                                        {advertisment.province === "V" ? 
                                        <p className="text-neutral-600 text-xs font-normal creator-text px-2">Provincia: Valencia</p>
                                        :null}
                                        {advertisment.province === "A" ? 
                                        <p className="text-neutral-600 text-xs font-normal creator-text px-2">Provincia: Alicante</p>
                                        :null}
                                        {advertisment.province === "C" ? 
                                        <p className="text-neutral-600 text-xs font-normal creator-text px-2">Provincia: Castellón</p>
                                        :null}
                                        
                                        <h3 className="font-medium text-neutral-800 doc-title px-2 my-1">{advertisment.title}</h3>
                                        <div className=" text-neutral-600 text-xs font-normal creator-text px-2 text-ellipsis line-clamp-2"><p className="parrafo">{advertisment.description}</p></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </button>
                            <div className="flex items-center justify-end mx-3">
                                <button className="bg-transparent text-teal-600 text-sm active:bg-teal-700 py-2 outline-none focus:outline-none underline uppercase" type="button" onClick={() => handleAddToDetail(advertisment)}>Ver más</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    :
                    <div className="hidden p-4 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-800" id="rent" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="rent-tab">
                    </div>
                }
```

Comment: Do you need session, local store, redux store or ss peristency?
Reload is used in too many case for not entirely the same thing.